# Keep Global Variables Constant in Postman?

Tags: automated-tests, postman, web-api-testing

**Background**

I have a variable in postman and i randomly generate an uid for creating a userid for signup and login test.

**Work Done in Postman**

In signup Request, on the pre-request script

```
var uid="{{$randomInt}}"
postman.setGlobalVariable("IID",uid);`
```

In Login Request, body is set to :

```
  {"uid":"{{IID}}" }
```

**Issue**

The issue is everytime {{IID}} is executed,a new value is generated.

However,my motto is to create a userid randomly on signup and use it during

login,which fails as {{IID}} gives me a new uid ,instead of uid set

during Signup(using postman.setGlobalVariable("IID",uid);).

**Query**

Any ideas ,how to everytime randomly generate userid on start of flow and then use that userid in rest of flows in **POSTMAN**.

Flow is SignUp action followed by Login action.

Comment: was it resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use any [library available](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/sandbox) in sandbox mode to generate random ID in *pre-request script*.
You can even make `postman.setGlobalVariable("IID", Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));` or use lodash's _.random(min, max) for such purposes.
Everything else will work without changes(I mean "{{ID}}" in next requests' body/headers/URL)